# My Remote Desktop option is missing - what should I do?

Tags: linux-mint

I need to enable remote connections to a machine that's running Linux Mint 13 Maya. I understand from tutorials like [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqlZq8LzBq4) that Remote Desktop ought to be one of the options in my Preferences menu, but it isn't. It's also missing from Control Center. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If there is a "Desktop Sharing" option try that. If not, first try and run the desktop sharing manager (vino) manually. Open a terminal and type:

```
vino-preferences
```

After you hit enter, the desktop sharing options should appear. If they do not, or you get an error message, you may need to install vino:

```
sudo apt-get install vino
```

Comment: Thanks! There was no "Desktop Sharing" option, but I was able to run vino manually. I'll report back after trying a remote login.